# Passing variables to custom Django template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm adding an autocomplete feature to my django application.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            var a = {% get_fields_task_name %}
            $( "#auto_task_name" ).autocomplete({
              source: a           
            });
```

view

```
def get_fields_task_name():    
    task = Task.objects.all()    
    output = []

    for e in task:
        output.append(e.name)

    x = json.dumps(output)
    return x
get_fields_task_name = register.simple_tag(get_fields_task_name)
```

I need to pass parameters to `get_fields_task_name`, how can I do this in the template instead of `{% get_fields_task_name %}`?

Comment: I agree that Dougal's solution would work.  But it seems to me that a normal view function would be an easier way to handle this logic, as opposed to a template tag.  I think more context is necessary to come up with the optimal answer.

Comment: @BenRosnick Right...now that I think about it, I don't see any advantage of doing this through a template tag rather than just passing it in from the original view.

Answer (score 9):

This depends on exactly what the parameters are, but if it's something you can get in a single variable at template rendering time, just add it as a parameter to the function ([see the docs for `simple_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)).

For example:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_fields_task_name(kind):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(kind=kind)
    return json.dumps([e.name for e in tasks])
```

(using a list comprehension to make the function body shorter and cleaner, and also using the nicer decorator syntax).

Then you can just change the relevant line in the template to

```
var a = {% get_fields_task_name some_variable.kind %};
```